# Least groups with most people given a list of people with their possible groups

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say that I have a list of people (15-20 people), each person can belong to one of a list of acceptable groups. For example:

- Bob - Art, Crafts
- Alice - Crafts, Politics
- Jean - Crafts, Sports, Literature
- Sally - Sports, Art
- Barbara - Politics, Sports

e.t.c

Once assigned - the person can't belong to another group. A person can only be assigned to one of the groups they have on their list.

How can I assign people to groups so that there would be the least amount of groups? (I don't care if one group is very full and another is very empty, I just want to have the least amount of groups).

In the above example, an acceptable result would be:

- Crafts: Bob, Alice, Jean
- Sports: Sally, Barbara

Comment: Looks like the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: This is not group theory. Group theory is about a certain type of algebraic structure, not about groups/sets of things. Please read the tag descriptions before using so many inappropriate, incorrect tags.